# Lack of useful tags

Tags: discussion, tags

Every time I use this site I notice a real lack of tags. And there are less users than some of the other sites, so maybe lowering the threshold for tag creation or having some admins make a few would be helpful.

Comment: can you be more specific about what tags you'd like to see?

Comment: this could also be caused by the more nicheness of the site than say stackoverflow ... which could have all the tags of this site 10x.

Answer (score 8):

The requirement for creating tags is already low -- it's [300 reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/privileges/create-tags) instead of the [1500](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/create-tags) required on Stack Overflow. If you mention in a question or comment that you want a particular tag but it's unavailable, an editor will generally add it for you (it's nothing to do with mods or devs; you only need 300 to create a tag and [500](https://unix.stackexchange.com/privileges/retag-questions) to retag someone else's post). We can't just create tags arbitrarily, they have to be attached to a question

Answer (score 1):

As Michael said, the barrier for creating tags is already very low. Additionally there are a number of people who regularly read all incoming questions and help with tags as necessary. If you leave a comment on any of your questions that you feel needs a new tag, we will consider adding it for you.

That being said I looked at the questions you have asked, and couldn't think of any tags that would be needed. There was at least one relevant tag that you hadn't used, but it already existed.

Also remember that tags don't do your question much good if they are the only question on the site with that tag. They are only useful for searching, sorting and focusing attention in-so-far as they categorize multiple questions. We will probably not add tags if there is only ever going to be one question that uses it, but if we think there is any chance of more questions showing up with that tag and it being a useful delimiter we won't hesitate to add it.